# docker-compose: how to prevent volume binding to host from syncing two copies of data?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, bind, docker-volume

docker-compose: volume binding to host sync two copies of data. e.g.,

```
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:latest
    volumes:
      - myapp_data:/opt/myapp/data

volumes:
  myapp_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/myapp/data
```

When writing data to /opt/myapp/data in the container, it will be written to both volume (/var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp_data/_data) and host (home/myapp/data).

How to prevent syncing two copies of data? Just need to have the data on host.

The reason of using volume instead of

```
services:
  tomcat:
    image: tomcat:latest
    volumes:
      - /home/myapp/data:/opt/myapp/data
```

is the initial data copy from container to volume. Direct bind without volume will not copy initial data to host directory (empty).

Comment: With a Linux bind mount, the same content appears in two different places in the filesystem, but you don't have two copies of it.  You can experiment with mount(8) without Docker too.  (In general you shouldn't look inside `/var/lib/docker` at all; I'd also try to avoid relying on the volume-copy behavior, which has some significant limitations.)